# get variables substituted when I cat a file

Tags: bash, shell, variables, sh, cat

Is it possible, in a clean way to get the variable values when I cat a file, instead of the variable names, as written in the file. It's hard to explain, but here goes a simple example:

```
$ cat <<EOF
$HOME
EOF
/home/myself
```

cat returns /home/myself because it is already expanded by the shell.

```
$ echo \$HOME >/tmp/home
$ cat /tmp/home
$HOME
```

cat simply reads the file, I want $HOME to be expanded here somehow by cat, because the file will contain variable names (not like HOME=/home/myself)

My question is if this is possible somehow, otherwise I will have to write some dirty code.

EDIT: they are big xml files containing

```
<checkbox active="$value">
```

true or false

Comment: Would `echo \`cat /tmp/home\`` do?

Comment: What are the files really going to contain? Just the one variable name? Or are you trying to come up with some form of template engine that interpolates variable values into freeform text?

Comment: Beta@ nay...; sarnold@ big xml files containing "<checkbox active="$value">" true or false. I will source the values from other file in /etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be trivial to attempt in Python, and see if that works for you.  You could use the [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) function to replace all occurrences of some pattern like `"\$\w+"` by calling a function which does the transformation (rather than a specific string to replace it with).  And for the replacement function you could use `os.getenv()`, which of course takes a variable name and returns its value.

Edit: Here's a complete Python script that does the above:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fileinput
import os
import re

def transform(match):
    return os.getenv(match.group(1)) # replace the "capture" to omit $

for line in fileinput.input(): # reads from stdin or from a file in argv
    print re.sub('\$(\w+)', transform, line), # comma to omit newline
```

Comment: Hardly.  I will write the code for you shortly, and you will see how simple it is.

Answer (score 2):

I recently found a way to do this with `envsubst`:

```
export MYNAME="Jason"
echo '{ "status": 200, "message": { "name": "$MYNAME" } }' > my.json.template

cat my.json.template
# outputs { "status": 200, "message": { "name": "$MYNAME" } }    

cat my.json.template | envsubst
# outputs { "status": 200, "message": { "name": "Jason" } }
```

If you don't have the `envsubst` you can install it on debian distros with:

```
apt-get install gettext-base
```

Comment: in Bash it also can be made as short as `envsubst <my.json.template`

Answer (score 1):

`cat` copies its inputs unchanged to its outputs - at least in its original (1st Edition UNIX) form.  It didn't have any options to start with.  Then BSD added a bunch, and the original UNIX team objected: '`cat` came back from Berkeley waving flags' (see: [1](http://simson.net/ref/ugh.pdf) - passim).  It should not be used to edit files - that is not its purpose. (I found a reference to the article in the BSD (Mac OS X) man page for `cat`:  Rob Pike, *"UNIX Style, or cat -v Considered Harmful"*, USENIX Summer Conference Proceedings, 1983.  See also http://quotes.cat-v.org/programming/)

So, you need something other than `cat` to do the job.  I'd recommend Perl or Python; either can do it pretty easily.  Alternatively, consider `sed`, or perhaps `awk`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<>)
{
    foreach my $key (keys %ENV)
    {
        s/\$$key\b/$ENV{$key}/g;  # $envvar
        s/\${$key}/$ENV{$key}/g;  # ${envvar}
    }
    print;
}
```

This loops through the input line, looking for each environment variable in turn.  The alternative mechanism is to look for possible variables and do the relevant substitution.  This turns out to be a little tricky, but doable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<>)
{
    while (m/\$((\w+))/ || m/\$({(\w+)})/)
    {
        my $key = $2;
        my $var = $1;
        s/\$$var/$ENV{$key}/g if defined $ENV{$key};
    }
    print;
}
```

When I included the literal `$` in the captures, the substitute operation did not work correctly.

Comment: Yes, I had a look at cat man page, and it is designed just to read the file, though it can be used to write files with redirections. Your script also works very well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way to do this has a lot of problems:

```
# This will fail with certain inputs.  HTML will certainly be a problem
# as the '<' and '>' characters will be interpreted as file redirects
$ while read r; do eval echo $r; done < input
```

The following perl should handle the problem fairly well for simple inputs.

```
$ perl -pwe 'while(($k,$v) = each %ENV ) { s/\${?$k}?/$v/ }' input
```

But it doesn't do anything with constructs like ${FOO-bar}.  If you need to handle such constructs, it might be sufficient to escape all of the shell meta-characters and do the while/read loop:

```
$ sed -e 's/\([<>&|();]\)/\\\1/g' input | while read -r l; do eval echo "$l"; done
```

Note that this is neither robust nor secure.  Consider what happens on input like:

```
\; rm -rf /
```

I said "consider".  Do not test that.  The sed will insert a backslash before the semicolon, the eval will then get the string "\\;" which will be interpreted as a single backslash followed by a semi-colon which termintates the echo, and the rm -rf will be executed.  Given the insecurity of evaling unknown input, it would probably be safer to stick with something like perl and explicitly replace the desired sh constructs.  Something like:

```
$ perl -pwe 'while(($k,$v) = each %ENV ) { s/\${?$k}?/$v/ }; 
    s/\${[^-]*-([^}]*)}/$1/g' input
```

This one has problems with input like ${FOO=some-text}.  In order to reliably get all of the sh constructs (${word:rhs} where the ':' can be any of '-', '?', '=', '+', '%', '#' or any of the same with a colon prepended (or a lot of other symbols if you allow non-posix sh syntax!)) you would have to construct a fairly elaborate set of comparisons.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about. If I use a sed command, I can use all bash constructs (I am kind of bashist and portabillity is not an issue in these scripts). The problem I found in your sed command is that all double quotes, aka \", disappear. The XML needs active="true", and fails on active=true. I need to keep the quotes from the XML, for many will **not** contain variables. How can we improve this sed command?

Comment: @Teresa Just adding a " in the list of characters to be escaped should do the trick.  I think I'd stick with perl, though, as the possible consequences of eval-ing unkown input can be pretty severe.